# What would be the best way to accomplish this If-else check?

Tags: php

I have an if-else statement in a php class, which works perfectly. I want to know if there could be an any better or faster way to accomplish this?

```
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="text" name="value_1" value="" ><br>
 <br>
<input type="text" name="value_2" value="" ><br>
 <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<?php  

$value_1 = $_POST['value_1'];
$value_1 = $_POST['value_2'];
$default = 'value_default';

if( !empty($value_1) && empty($value_2)){
    echo $value_1;
} elseif( !empty($value_2) && empty($value_1) ){
    echo $value_2;
} elseif (!empty($value_1) && !empty($value_2)){
    echo $value_1 .' - '. $value_2;
} else {
    echo $default;
}

?>
```

In my Code, there are 4 conditions,

1. Value 1 is set (in this case value 2 will be empty)
2. Value 2 is set (in this case value 1 will be empty)
3. Both the values are set (in this case both values are set)
4. Both the values are empty (none of the values are set)

All the values will be sent to the function via a normal HTML form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please note that you should be posting working code in your question, not pseudo code. It is a general rule for Code Review questions.

There is also a problem with your pseudo code. Your `function_3` will never get executed. Note that the first two `if` blocks require either `$value_1` or `$value_2` to be filled, which is exactly what the third `if` block states. Since it is in the third position it will never get executed. You would have know this if it was actual code. That's one of the reasons you should post working code.

So it can be rewitten as:

```
if (empty($value_1)) {
    if (empty($value_2)) {
        function_default(){ }
    }
    else {
        function_2(){ }
    } 
} elseif (empty($value_2)) {
    function_1(){ } 
}
```

But I doubt this is useful to you, since you clearly want to do something else.

Your code suggests you want to define functions depending on certain conditions. I cannot think of any good reason to do this. Can you give me one?

So, can your code be written better? Yes, it clearly can. Can it be made faster? Given the little code you've written, I have to say: No.

Comment: Since downvoters hardly ever tell you why they downvote, I have to assume that they regards any answer to a bad question a bad answer. But is that always true? Or might there be a valid reason for the downvotes?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have updated my question. The code I posted works well for me. I just want to make it more robust. Yes, First 2 If require either value_1 or value_2 to be set but my third if require both the value_1 and value_2 to be set/non-empty.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I’d assume the same, since [you should refrain from answering off-topic questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/84718).

Comment: @DeepakSingh You're using an `||` (= or) in the third condition, so it says: "if value1 is set or value2 is set". It will be false when both are set. Perhaps you intend to use an `&&` (= and)?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger There don't seem to be strict rules about this, and voting on an answer based purely on the question seems silly. I used an answer because it is longer than fitted in a comment: 1. don't use psuedo code. 2. There's a bug in your code. 3. Why conditionally create functions? In general there's a lack of good documentation on Code Review. How can someone know how to ask a question when all they have to go on is [this mess](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)? (also read next comment)

Comment: @DeepakSingh: Why you start asking a question it says: "Your question **must contain code that is already working correctly**, and the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question. Please avoid stripping out key details that may be relevant to the review.". You question still doesn't fulfill this prerequisite.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It's not silly to deincentivize answers to off-topic questions - It's not behavior we want. If you need to write a comment that doesn't fit in a comment box, make it a [disposable CW](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6977).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am sorry for the mistake about &&. Yes, It is &&. And I am confused about what more details should I post. I simply posted what is my actual problem. Posting full code will make it just complex, and unrelated. I am not creating function conditionally, instead, I am just executing them conditionally. First I posted it on StackOverflow I got suggestions there to post it here, so I did. Understanding and answering this is very easy, but since tomorrow I am just getting the downvotes and suggestion on how to post instead of getting a solution. BTW, Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thank your suggestion worked great for me.

Comment: @DeepakSingh If you've learned what you needed to know then I wouldn't bother revising the question. Just accept the downvotes, they do happen from time to time. Just remember that Code Review demands working code, and is quite strict about that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes, It was my first post here. I will take care of this, from the next time.